# Making data in View Bold

Tags: c#, html, css, model-view-controller

I need to make some data bold in my view.

here is the code:

```
<table class="CSSTableGenerator">
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Bdata)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                 @item.Month
            </td>

            <td>
                @item.Month1
            </td>              
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I need `@item.Month` to be bold.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it by appropriate `<b></b>` tags:

```
<td>
     <b>@item.Month</b>
</td>
```

Comment: Have you checked html page source after using these tags in the view source code? Does it contains `<b>` tag? Browser can show you cached version of the page. Try to force reload it (Ctrl-F5 in most browsers).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "didn't work"? Does view contains `<b>` tag and output html doesn't? Or both contains that tag but font is not bold? Also - have you recompiled/restared your ASP.NET project after modifying the view?

Comment: both contain the tag but font is not bold

Comment: Make sure there is a bold version of the font. Check out my answer. @simba

Comment: @SoorajChandran I tried Sooraj it didn't work don't know what is the issue

Comment: Which font are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make your text bold:

1. strong Tag

```html
<strong>@item.Month</strong>
```

1. Css atrribute

```html
<td style="font weight :bold;">@item.Month</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods.

**using `b`**

```
<td>
     <b>@item.Month</b>
</td>
```

**using `strong`**

```
<td>
  <strong>@item.Month</strong>
</td>
```

strong is better for SEO.

**or using CSS**

```
.CSSTableGenerator td
{
 font-weight:bold; //or specify the font-weight you require.
}
```

Make sure that the font you use have a bold version for all of this to work. If you are using google fonts you will need to download the bolder versions also.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the definition of the class "CSSTableGenerator" actually the font was already defined bold in the css. I am working on a module of already created project that is why i was unaware of it. Sorry for wasting your time guys. I guess you all were right, my bad.